# Type.GetTypeFromProgID does not work on ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, com-interop

I have used below snippet of code to load COM object in Web API 2 (.NET 4.5) and it worked fine.

```
Type myType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyProgramID.ABC");                
if (myType != null)
{    
    dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
}
```

However the same above code does not work in ASP.NET Web API Core 2.0. The return of Type.GetTypeFromProgID() is not the DLL I want to load.

I read some articles to say that .NET core 2.0 already support Type.GetTypeFromProgID() but it did not work for my case.

Any thought? 
Appreciate a lot in advance.

Kelvin

Comment: Why are you using COM interop in the first place? Is there no alternative for that COM component? Also, what's the bitness of your application? It has to match the bitness of the COM component (32 or 64-bit)

Comment: because I don't want to re-write/port the COM code into .NET Core if possible. I used AnyCPU target for both COM and ASP.NET Core